# Awesomium 1.7.5.1 in console application

Tags: c#, awesomium

I can't get awesomium to work in a console application no matter what I do. Most of the samples I gathered over the internet are either for older versions or don't work at all. All I want to do is download a page, here is my code:

```
  private static SynchronizationContext _context;
  private static readonly ManualResetEvent AwesomiumReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  private readonly ManualResetEvent _mainFrameLoaded = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  private static Thread _awesomeThread;

  ...

  public AwesomiumPageDownloader()
  {
     Initialise();
  }

  private static void Initialise()
  {
     if(_awesomeThread != null) return;  //ignore concurrent initialisation problem for now

     _awesomeThread = new Thread(() =>
     {
        WebCore.Started += (s, e) =>
        {
           _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
           AwesomiumReady.Set();
        };

        WebCore.Run();
     });
     _awesomeThread.Name = "Awesomium Worker";

     _awesomeThread.Start();

     WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig());

     AwesomiumReady.WaitOne();
  }

  public string Download(string url)
  {
     _mainFrameLoaded.Reset();

     _context.Post(state =>
     {
        using(WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768))
        {

           view.Source = new Uri(url);

           view.LoadingFrameComplete += (sender, e) =>
           {
              if(!e.IsMainFrame)
              {
                 _mainFrameLoaded.Set();
                 return;
              }
           };

           view.DocumentReady += (sender, args) =>
           {
              _mainFrameLoaded.Set();
           };
        }
     }, null);

     _mainFrameLoaded.WaitOne();

     return null;
  }
```

I never get LoadingFrameCompleted or DocumentReady no matter what I try.

This is a console application with STAThread and 32bit.

Comment: Are you doing this to take screenshots or something? Why do you want to use a UI component in a console application?

Comment: I need to get full HTML after all js has rendered the DOM. I'm thinking now to just write an external process as winforms App as winforms conpomment works as magic, but that's ugly.

Comment: I went for a wi winforms control launched in external process from a server. Anyway this is more reliable, and awesomium requires 32bit which is not enough, and it can crash because of native libraries.